# "How do I switch between PostgreSQL users using a specific user?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having an issue while attempting to switch between users in PostgreSQL. I have multiple roles created in my database, each with specific permissions to interact with it. I understand that using the command SET ROLE (role_name) should allow me to switch between roles. However, when I attempt this command, it says, "You do not have permission to set the role." It's worth noting that I connect to the specific database with a created user, not 'postgres'. I'd like to know what kind of permission I need to grant to my user to enable the use of SET ROLE.

These are my created users:

```
CREATE ROLE administrador LOGIN; 
CREATE ROLE usuario LOGIN; 
CREATE ROLE empleado LOGIN; 
CREATE ROLE mantenimiento LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE nologin;

CREATE USER cinelife WITH PASSWORD 'qwertyuiop' LOGIN;
```

cinelife is the user connecting to the specific database in question.

Comment: 1) You repeated your question 2) The answer is in the docs [SET ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You are the best, bro, sorry if the question was a bit stupid hahaha